# ccache : Failed to create temporary file

Tags: android, android-source, ubuntu-22.04, ccache

I have been trying to build android 13-plus for a while and while building I keep encountering the error:

```
ccache: error: Failed to create temporary file for /mnt/ccache/tmp/tmp.cpp_stdout.3Xmuoo: Permission denied
18:32:57 ninja failed with: exit status 1
```

I tried using the answers available on stack, reddit as well as github. But So, far I had no answers.

These are the commands I tried after the error in the given image.

[Error Commands:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WGhQ.png) which are similar to what stack also recommended

Comment: If you have any questions then please write them in your post.

Comment: No pictures please. Write text as text.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the ownership of the directory where ccache directory is set.

Example: `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /path/to/dir`